# Center Align horizontal images in a table TD

Tags: html, css

I have a JSFIDDLE created where I have pasted code picked up online from another stack exchange thread to show how to have responsive tables with scrolling. I modified that code while testing the approach and it works great on my machine. the only problem I am having is that the TD I have has images in the same line as seen in the fiddle, but the images are bottom aligned. Basically, I want the images to be center aligned vertically. So that even if the images have different heights, they are center aligned while scrolling horizontally. Any suggestions please? The image boundaries are visible although the image links are broken since I did not want to link to random images on the internet.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emailthehunk/6pjor8g4/1/)

```
<tr>
<td><img src = "test.gif" height="100px" width="500px"><img src = "test.gif" height="300px" width="600px"></td>
</tr>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`td img { vertical-align: middle; }` may be all that's needed. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6pjor8g4/2/)

Comment: Can you explain to him why?

Answer (score 0):

```
td img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This will make all images inside the td vertically aligned in the middle, not the bottom.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wowsk/qdnov5q3/)